# Logic Apps Json not array

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps

I am currently working on a Logic app that makes retention possible in the way we want it for Microsoft teams. With this app, I have a lot of API calls that I Parse to a JSON file. What really grinds my gears is when it makes a For each loop every time I want to have a value from the JSON even if there is only 1 value in the JSON. Does anybody know if you can avoid the for each loop in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know you always want the first value in an array you can use the expression editor and write `first(body(‘someActionName’)[‘some’][‘array’])` which would return the first value in some array without a foreach loop. If it’s an array of objects, could even continue to parse json

`first(body(‘someActionName’)[‘some’][‘array’])[‘otherProperty’]`

This is more or less the same as `body(‘someActionName’)[‘some’][‘array’][0]`